# LINQ query — Data aggregation (group adjacent)

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Let's take a class called `Cls`:

```
public class Cls
{
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's populate some collection with following elements:

```
Sequence
Number      Value
========    =====
1           9
2           9
3           15
4           15
5           15
6           30
7           9
```

What I need to do, is to enumerate over Sequence Numbers and check if the next element has the same value. If yes, values are aggregated and so, desired output is as following:

```
Sequence    Sequence
Number      Number
From        To          Value
========    ========    =====
1           2           9
3           5           15
6           6           30
7           7           9
```

How can I perform this operation using LINQ query?

Comment: I reckon you're gonna need to use a standard for-each loop here, interesting question though, and well put +1

Comment: Very interesting question, but I somehow doubt that LINQ version will be much more readable than the foreach loop version. I'm hoping an answer here can prove me otherwise.

Comment: You could group by value and then search the grouped collections for contiguous sequences, then split by them and sort by "from", but I think I agree the imperative version won't be much less readable in this particular case.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7064157/21727

Comment: See the same problem at CodeGolf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10797/group-adjacent-values

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Linq's `GroupBy` in a modified version which groups only if the two items are adjacent, then it's easy as:

```
var result = classes
    .GroupAdjacent(c => c.Value)
    .Select(g => new { 
        SequenceNumFrom = g.Min(c => c.SequenceNumber),
        SequenceNumTo = g.Max(c => c.SequenceNumber),  
        Value = g.Key
    });

foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine("SequenceNumFrom:{0} SequenceNumTo:{1} Value:{2}", x.SequenceNumFrom, x.SequenceNumTo, x.Value);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/elughG)

Result:

```
SequenceNumFrom:1  SequenceNumTo:2  Value:9
SequenceNumFrom:3  SequenceNumTo:5  Value:15
SequenceNumFrom:6  SequenceNumTo:6  Value:30
SequenceNumFrom:7  SequenceNumTo:7  Value:9
```

This is the extension method to to group adjacent items:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        TKey last = default(TKey);
        bool haveLast = false;
        List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>();
        foreach (TSource s in source)
        {
            TKey k = keySelector(s);
            if (haveLast)
            {
                if (!k.Equals(last))
                {
                    yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
                    list = new List<TSource>();
                    list.Add(s);
                    last = k;
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(s);
                    last = k;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
                haveLast = true;
            }
        }
        if (haveLast)
            yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
    }
}
```

and the class used:

```
public class GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    private List<TSource> GroupList { get; set; }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TSource> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var s in GroupList)
            yield return s;
    }
    public GroupOfAdjacent(List<TSource> source, TKey key)
    {
        GroupList = source;
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, that's a lot of code though, I think I would just use a regular for-each loop and build a new collection that way

Comment: Lots of code? It's a completely reusable, generalized solution. Not a lot, given that. Fantastic answer and a new tool for the toolbox. +1

Comment: The original source for this code appears to be https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/04/20/the-groupadjacent-extension-method/

Comment: @Quails4Eva: i must admit that i really don't know where the original source was, i'm fairly sure that it wasn't me, but i don't know that blog either. The author says: "this approach was suggested by one of the LINQ architects a year or two ago", so he's not the real author either.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter That is a fair point. I would interpret that as they suggested the approach and he wrote the code, or at least that the LINQ architect's version isn't publicly available. Regardless, I'm not too worried about it, it just seemed strange to me to find identical solutions 5 years apart so I added a link to the earlier version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this linq query

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Cd78qv)

```
var values = (new[] { 9, 9, 15, 15, 15, 30, 9 }).Select((x, i) => new { x, i });

var query = from v in values
            let firstNonValue = values.Where(v2 => v2.i >= v.i && v2.x != v.x).FirstOrDefault()
            let grouping = firstNonValue == null ? int.MaxValue : firstNonValue.i
            group v by grouping into v
            select new
            {
              From = v.Min(y => y.i) + 1,
              To = v.Max(y => y.i) + 1,
              Value = v.Min(y => y.x)
            };
```

Answer (score 3):

### [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) provides this functionality out of the box

It's called `GroupAdjacent` and is implemented as extension method on `IEnumerable`:

> Groups the adjacent elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function.

```
enumerable.GroupAdjacent(e => e.Key)
```

There is even a [Nuget "source" package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.GroupAdjacent/) that contains only that method, if you don't want to pull in an additional [binary Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.1.0).

The method returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>`, so its output can be processed in the same way output from `GroupBy` would be.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer.  I personally prefer adding the nuget package to copy/paste.  Besides, it's worth understanding what else is in MoreLinq that I've been missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var all = new [] {
    new Cls(1, 9)
,   new Cls(2, 9)
,   new Cls(3, 15)
,   new Cls(4, 15)
,   new Cls(5, 15)
,   new Cls(6, 30)
,   new Cls(7, 9)
};
var f = all.First();
var res = all.Skip(1).Aggregate(
    new List<Run> {new Run {From = f.SequenceNumber, To = f.SequenceNumber, Value = f.Value} }
,   (p, v) => {
    if (v.Value == p.Last().Value) {
        p.Last().To = v.SequenceNumber;
    } else {
        p.Add(new Run {From = v.SequenceNumber, To = v.SequenceNumber, Value = v.Value});
    }
    return p;
});
foreach (var r in res) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} : {2}", r.From, r.To, r.Value);
}
```

The idea is to use `Aggregate` creatively: starting with a list consisting of a single `Run`, examine the content of the list we've got so far at each stage of aggregation (the `if` statement in the lambda). Depending on the last value, either continue the old run, or start a new one.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/NJzZC4).

Comment: IMHO it's better to use a `foreach` loop when there is that much code in a lambda.

Comment: @juharr It's not just the amount of code, it's the fact that it's causing side effects and depending on those side effects.  When the important parts of any LINQ call cause side effects it usually means that portion should just be in a `foreach`.

Comment: @Servy I agree - I would not use LINQ for run detection precisely for the reason of side effects. I view this as a cure answer to a LINQ puzzle, because the OP asked for LINQ explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish it by creating a custom extension method.

```
static class Extensions {
  internal static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> GroupAdj(this IEnumerable<Cls> enumerable) {
    Cls start = null;
    Cls end = null;
    int value = Int32.MinValue;

    foreach (Cls cls in enumerable) {
      if (start == null) {
        start = cls;
        end = cls;
        continue;
      }

      if (start.Value == cls.Value) {
        end = cls;
        continue;
      }

      yield return Tuple.Create(start.SequenceNumber, end.SequenceNumber, start.Value);
      start = cls;
      end = cls;
    }

    yield return Tuple.Create(start.SequenceNumber, end.SequenceNumber, start.Value);
  }
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```
static void Main() {
  List<Cls> items = new List<Cls> {
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 1, Value = 9 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 2, Value = 9 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 3, Value = 15 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 4, Value = 15 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 5, Value = 15 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 6, Value = 30 },
    new Cls { SequenceNumber = 7, Value = 9 }
  };

  Console.WriteLine("From  To    Value");
  Console.WriteLine("===== ===== =====");
  foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(i => i.SequenceNumber).GroupAdj()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-5} {2,-5}", item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);
  }
}
```

And the expected output:

```
From  To    Value
===== ===== =====
1     2     9
3     5     15
6     6     30
7     7     9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation without any helper methods:

```
var grp = 0;
var results =
from i
in
input.Zip(
    input.Skip(1).Concat(new [] {input.Last ()}),
    (n1, n2) => Tuple.Create(
        n1, (n2.Value == n1.Value) ? grp : grp++
    )
)
group i by i.Item2 into gp
select new {SequenceNumFrom = gp.Min(x => x.Item1.SequenceNumber),SequenceNumTo = gp.Max(x => x.Item1.SequenceNumber), Value = gp.Min(x => x.Item1.Value)};
```

The idea is:

- Keep track of your own grouping indicator, grp.
- Join each item of the collection to the next item in the collection (via Skip(1) and Zip).
- If the Values match, they are in the same group; otherwise, increment grp to signal the start of the next group.

Answer (score 1):

Untested dark magic follows. The imperative version seems like it would be easier in this case.

```
IEnumerable<Cls> data = ...;
var query = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Value = g.Key,
        Sequences = g
            .OrderBy(x => x.SequenceNumber)
            .Select((x,i) => new
            {
                x.SequenceNumber,
                OffsetSequenceNumber = x.SequenceNumber - i
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.OffsetSequenceNumber)
            .Select(g => g
                .Select(x => x.SequenceNumber)
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .ToList())
            .ToList()
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Sequences
        .Select(s => new { First = s.First(), Last = s.Last(), x.Value }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.First)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose another option, which yields lazily both sequence of groups and
elements inside groups.

[Demonstration in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C5j0Ds)

Implementation:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
    {
        var comparerOrDefault = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        using var iterator = new Iterator<TSource>(source.GetEnumerator());
        iterator.MoveNext();
        while (iterator.HasCurrent)
        {
            var key = keySelector(iterator.Current);
            var elements = YieldAdjacentElements(iterator, key, keySelector, comparerOrDefault);
            yield return new Grouping<TKey, TSource>(key, elements);
            while (iterator.HasCurrentWithKey(key, keySelector, comparerOrDefault))
            {
                iterator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> YieldAdjacentElements<TKey, TSource>(
        Iterator<TSource> iterator,
        TKey key,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        while (iterator.HasCurrentWithKey(key, keySelector, comparer))
        {
            yield return iterator.Current;
            iterator.MoveNext();
        }
    }

    private static bool HasCurrentWithKey<TKey, TSource>(
        this Iterator<TSource> iterator,
        TKey key,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) =>
        iterator.HasCurrent && comparer.Equals(keySelector(iterator.Current), key);

    private sealed class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
        {
            Key = key;
            Elements = elements;
        }

        public TKey Key { get; }

        public IEnumerable<TElement> Elements { get; }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => Elements.GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => Elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private sealed class Iterator<T> : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

        public Iterator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
        {
            _enumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public bool HasCurrent { get; private set; }

        public T Current => _enumerator.Current;

        public void MoveNext()
        {
            HasCurrent = _enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, that it is impossible to achieve such level of laziness with regular `GroupBy` operation, since it needs to look through the whole collection before yielding the first group.

Particularly, in my case migration from `GroupBy` to `GroupAdjacent` in connection with lazy handling of whole pipeline helped to resolve memory consumption issues for large sequences.

In general, `GroupAdjacent` can be used as lazy and more efficient alternative of `GroupBy`, provided that input collection satisfies condition, that keys are sorted (or at least not fragmented), and provided that all operations in pipeline are lazy.