# use linq to aggregate text file contents so that they are grouped

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

Given the following query.

```
var query = files
            .SelectMany(file => File.ReadAllLines(file))
            .Where(_ => !_.StartsWith("*"))
            .Select(line => new {
                Order = line.Substring(32, 7),
                Delta = line.Substring(40, 3),
                Line = new String[] { line }
            });
```

This clearly produces a list of objects with the properties `Order: string`, `Delta: string` and `Line: string[]`

I have a list of items that looks like this.

```
{ 1, 'A', {'line1'} }, 
{ 1, 'A', {'line2'} }, 
{ 2, 'B', {'line3'} }, 
{ 1, 'B', {'line4 } }
```

is it possible to use the Linq `Aggregate` or similar functional construct to collect all the *adjacent* `Order` and `Delta` combinations together whilst accumulating the lines.

So that the aggregate is a list of items containing all it's 'lines'

```
{ 1, 'A', {'line1', 'line2'} }
{ 2, 'B', {'line3'} }
{ 1, 'B', {'line4'} }
```

Since aggregation iterates sequentially it should be possible to collect all the adjacent lines that have the same fields equal.

It's easy to do in a loop, but I am trying to do it with a set of lambdas.

Comment: I think you could use `Enumerable.Aggregate` to do this.  I'd have to play around with it to get it working though.  If you don't get an answer by the time I get back from lunch, I'll see what I can come up with.  If this has to pass through Entity Framework, it's probably a no-go though. Are you using EF?

Comment: `Aggregate` works by taking the current element and the accumulator, and creating a new accumulator. This isn't what you're doing, so I don't think it's a good match (although you could make it work, but in an ugly and hard-to-read way). What you want is a linq method which yields consecutive "equal" elements, where equality is determined by a delegate. There's nothing built in which does this, although you could write your own (which is just generalising the loop that's easy for you to write). Alternatively, it looks like MoreLinq's GroupAdjacent does this

Comment: Sorry, the example I linked to earlier was for grouping by *consecutive* numbers, not *adjacent*.  Deleted to avoid confusion.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879567/4499267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the following variation of `GroupBy`:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public class AdjacentGrouping<K, T> : List<T>, IGrouping<K, T>
    {
        public AdjacentGrouping(K key) { Key = key; }
        public K Key { get; private set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<K, T>> GroupByAdjacent<T, K>(
                            this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, K> keySelector)
    {
        using (var it = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!it.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            T curr = it.Current;
            K currKey = keySelector(curr);
            var currentCluster = new AdjacentGrouping<K, T>(currKey) { curr };
            while (it.MoveNext())
            {
                curr = it.Current;
                currKey = keySelector(curr);
                if (!EqualityComparer<K>.Default.Equals(currKey, currentCluster.Key))
                {
                    // start a new cluster
                    yield return currentCluster;
                    currentCluster = new AdjacentGrouping<K, T>(currKey);
                }
                currentCluster.Add(curr);
            };
            // currentCluster is never empty
            yield return currentCluster;
        }
    }
}
```

Having this adjacent grouping, your code can be the same as in [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54889276/276994):

```
var query = files
    .SelectMany(file => File.ReadAllLines(file))
    .Where(_ => !_.StartsWith("*"))
    .Select(line => new
    {
        Order = line.Substring(32, 7),
        Delta = line.Substring(40, 3),
        Line = new String[] { line }
    })
    .GroupByAdjacent(o => new { o.Order, o.Delta })
    .Select(g => new { g.Key.Order, g.Key.Delta, Lines = g.Select(o => o.Line).ToList() });
```

---

Disclaimer: the function `GroupByAdjacent` is from my own pet project and not copied from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @vlad I was hoping there would be a simpler way... but this is great thanks for sharing

Comment: @Jim: I was hoping it too some time ago, but after some fruitless research found out that it's actually simpler to impelment it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Does not group items by adjacency**

You can produce the desired results using a simple [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) combined with a [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var query = new[] {
  new { order = 1, delta = "A", line = new[] { "line1" } },
  new { order = 1, delta = "A", line = new[] { "line2" } },
  new { order = 2, delta = "B", line = new[] { "line3" } },
  new { order = 1, delta = "B", line = new[] { "line4" } },
};

query
  .GroupBy(q => new { q.order, q.delta })
  .Select(q => new {
    order = q.Key.order,
    delta = q.Key.delta,
    lines = q.SelectMany(l => l.line)
});
```

Produces:

[image: resultset]

Comment: I don't think this is right - he wanted *adjacent* groupings. Add a new element with `order = 1, delta = "A"` at the end.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly sure what this adjacent requirement means. Will remove answer if OP confirms this doesn't address his issue.

Comment: My understanding, and I think this is pretty clear from the question, is that if two *consecutive* elements have the same order and delta, then they should be grouped. If there are elements with the same order and delta which are not consecutive, then they should not be grouped.

Comment: @Chris meaning only group elements next to eachother that match on order and delta, not all orders and deltas in the collection