# From the given code, I display only 1 most repetitive number, i.e. 6, 6, 6, 6, But I also want to bring out the second one either: 3, 3, 3, 3,

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace 2258864
{
    class Program
    {
        static void MostRepeatedInARow(int[] array)
        {
            int MostRepCount = 0, count = 1;
            int? Mostrepeated = null;

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] == array[i - 1])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (count > MostRepCount)
                    {
                        MostRepCount = count;
                        Mostrepeated = array[i - 1];
                        count = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Number {Mostrepeated} repeated {MostRepCount} times in a row.");
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] ListofNumbers = { 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2 };

            
            MostRepeatedInARow(ListofNumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the number and count of each unique number in a data structure of some sort (a `List<Tuple<int, int>>`, perhaps?).  Then you can do whatever you want with the resulting "histogram."

Comment: I like Robert's idea, but I'd go with `Dictionary<int, int>` because it's easier to look up values with that, and because there's no need to support duplicate keys.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879197/linq-query-data-aggregation-group-adjacent.  (It is likely overkill, but does handle grouping of adjacent values.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A basic implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static (IReadOnlyCollection<T> MostRepeatedItems, int LongestRepetition) FindLongestRepetitions<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var currentLongestRepetitions = new HashSet<T>();
    var longestRepetition = 0;
    T previousItem = default;
    var foundAny = false;
    var currentRepetition = 0;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
       if (!foundAny)
       {
           foundAny = true;
           currentRepetition = 1;
       }
       else if (item.Equals(previousItem))
       {
           currentRepetition += 1;
       }
       else
       {
           currentRepetition = 1;
       }
       
       if (currentRepetition > longestRepetition)
       {
           currentLongestRepetitions = new HashSet<T> {item};
           longestRepetition = currentRepetition;
       }
       else if (currentRepetition == longestRepetition)
       {
           currentLongestRepetitions.Add(item);
       }

       previousItem = item;
    }

    return (currentLongestRepetitions, longestRepetition);
}


int[] numbers = { 4, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2 };
var (mostRepeatedNumbers, longestRepetition) = FindLongestRepetitions(numbers);
Console.WriteLine($"The most repeated numbers were: {string.Join(',', mostRepeatedNumbers)}.");
Console.WriteLine($"They were repeated {longestRepetition} times.");
```

Try it out [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: This code is acceptable and really does what I need it to do. But: Unfortunately my sensei will not get a similar answer. Because I have not learned so much yet.I need to find an easier way. Thank you so much for the support though

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 static void MostRepeatedInARow(int[] array)
        {
            List<(int, int)> repeated=new List<(int,int)>();
            
              var count =1;
              
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] == array[i - 1])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                   (int, int) n= (array[i-1],count);
                    repeated.Add(n);
                    count = 1;
                };
                
            }
        repeated.Sort((s1, s2) => s2.Item2.CompareTo(s1.Item2));
        
        var howManyResults=2; // repeated.Count for all
        
        foreach (var item in repeated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Number {item.Item1} repeated {item.Item2} times in a row.");
            howManyResults--;
            if(howManyreSults==0) break;
        }
```

output

```
Number 6 repeated 4 times in a row.
Number 3 repeated 4 times in a row.
```

or

```
foreach (var item in repeated)
{
 if (item.Item2 >1)
  Console.WriteLine($"Number {item.Item1} repeated {item.Item2} times in a 
 row.");
 else
 {
 Console.WriteLine("All another numbers  don't repeat  in a row.");
 break;
 }
}
```

output

```
Number 6 repeated 4 times in a row.
Number 3 repeated 4 times in a row.
Number 5 repeated 3 times in a row.
All another numbers  don't repeat  in a row.
```